Missing video codec
I have a Samsung TV which can play video files from an external USB source.
Generally this works fine, however recently I've come across some mp4 files which it says it can't play. I was a little confused at first as it can usually play mp4's without a problem but on further investigation it seems the problematic files have no video codec.
Can I 'install' this codec somehow in the file?

Edit: I've added the TV model and the file info from the video files. Unfortunately I don't own the actual footage so cannot post here.
TV model at the top, followed by the working file, then the non working file. The missing video codec is obvious.



When I try to play a non working file, I get this error message.


Put the exact model of TV, and if you can (and own the footage), upload an example of a file that will & won't play.

@tomh I've added the relevant details

Check whether the second video can play on a PC or Mac.
If it can, it means the video codec isn't recognised by the Samsung TV.
Transcode the second video using a free tool like Handbrake.
Make sure the audio and video codec settings match those of the first working video.

Thank Tom, I'll try this.
The TV can play other H.264/MP4 files without problem so I know it recognises the codec.
